# want to get each Groups latest row, group by multiple column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I need to get the latest row of each combinations of sender_id & receiver_id

my `messaging` table:

```
CREATE TABLE messaging (
  msg_id SERIAL,
  sender_id BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
  receiver_id varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  msg text default NULL,
  media_link TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  sent_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  received_time TIMESTAMP default NULL,
  msg_type ENUM('text','link','file') default 'text',
  is_seen BINARY DEFAULT 0
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Sample data:

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|msg_id|sender_id|receiver_id|msg            |media_link|sent_time          |received_time|msg_type|is_seen|
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|1     |1        |10         |hi             |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:11:53|NULL         |text    |0      |
|2     |1        |10         |r u there?     |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:12:46|NULL         |text    |0      |
|3     |7        |10         |hi             |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:13:13|NULL         |text    |0      |
|4     |7        |10         |where r u from?|NULL      |2022-11-08 20:31:17|NULL         |text    |0      |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

ORDER BY latest with each sender_id receiver_id combination the result should look like this:

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|msg_id|sender_id|receiver_id|msg            |media_link|sent_time          |received_time|msg_type|is_seen|
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|2     |1        |10         |r u there?     |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:12:46|NULL         |text    |0      |
|4     |7        |10         |where r u from?|NULL      |2022-11-08 20:31:17|NULL         |text    |0      |
+------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

I have tried this statement:

```
SELECT msg_id, 
       sender_id, 
       receiver_id, 
       msg, 
       media_link, 
       sent_time, 
       received_time, 
       msg_type, 
       is_seen  
FROM messaging  
WHERE sender_id = 10 OR receiver_id = 10 
GROUP BY sender_id,receiver_id  
ORDER BY msg_id DESC;
```

which gives there rows ascending order of each group:

```
+------+---------+-----------+---+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|msg_id|sender_id|receiver_id|msg|media_link|sent_time          |received_time|msg_type|is_seen|
+------+---------+-----------+---+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|3     |7        |10         |hi |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:13:13|NULL         |text    |0      |
|1     |1        |10         |hi |NULL      |2022-11-08 19:11:53|NULL         |text    |0      |
+------+---------+-----------+---+----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

But it is only showing oldest row of each group by combination.

I am still learning Mysql. Please help me

Comment: please add the sample data and the expected results of that sample data

Comment: which timestamp column do you want to look at for fetching the recent row ?

Comment: @trillion sent_time column for recent rows

Comment: @techedifice i have added the solution below, should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you need a recent row, then there must be a specific timeframe field that you are looking at i.e sent_time
- you can use that timeframe field in the `ORDER BY` by clause of the `row_number()` function to create a rank. This rank would give a value of 1 for the most recent timeframe field with the combination of sennder and receiver id (see `partition by`  caluse )
- Lastly you can filter on rank_ = 1

```
with main as (
select 
*,
row_number() over(partition by sender_id, receiver_id order by sent_time desc) as rank_
from messaging
)
select * from main where rank_ = 1
```

Comment: not working giving error:[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'rank_' in 'where clause'

Comment: run the lastest solution, I have edited It just now

Comment: Is there any way to get only unique sender and receiver column UNIQUE like DISTINCT?, With your solution I am getting I sent some one a message he sent me a msg both are shown. Is there any way conversation between 2 users will be shown once and the latest one no metter who is sending or receiving?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify `NULL` when setting default value in `TIMESTAMP`, it will return an error.
Do it instead:

```
CREATE TABLE messaging (
  msg_id SERIAL,
  sender_id BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
  receiver_id varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
  msg text default NULL,
  media_link TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  sent_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  received_time TIMESTAMP NULL,
  msg_type ENUM('text','link','file') default 'text',
  is_seen BINARY DEFAULT 0
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    insert into messaging 
VALUES(  NULL,   123,  'ABC',  'THIS IS A TEXT',  DEFAULT,  DEFAULT,  NULL,  'text',  DEFAULT),
(  NULL,   456,  'DFG',  'TEXT THIS IS',  DEFAULT,  DEFAULT,  NULL,  'link',  DEFAULT),
(  NULL,   789,  'HIJ',  'MAY THE FORCE BE WITH',  DEFAULT,  DEFAULT,  NULL,  'link',  DEFAULT),
(  NULL,   456,  'KLM',  'YOU',  DEFAULT,  DEFAULT,  NULL,  'link',  DEFAULT);
```

I've found two ways to acheive to your need:

```
# UNION WAY
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT MAX(t.sender_id), 'sender_id' as type
FROM messaging t
union all
SELECT MAX(t2.receiver_id), 'receiver_id' as type
FROM messaging t2) t3;

# SUBSELECT WAY
SELECT MAX(sender_id) AS MAX_sender_id,
  (SELECT MAX(t2.receiver_id)
   FROM messaging t2) AS MAX_receiver_id 
FROM messaging t;
```

Check the result here -> [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ba205/1)

Let me know if it helped

Comment: nah, not working ur method just showing only  two columns not any required info

Comment: I did some changes to query, you can try it over here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76cadc/2/0

`select  
 (SELECT t3.sender_id
   FROM messaging t3
   WHERE t3.sender_id = t1.sender_id
   ORDER BY msg_id DESC
   LIMIT 1 ) AS MAX_sender_id,
  (SELECT t2.receiver_id
   FROM messaging t2
  WHERE t1.sender_id = t2.sender_id
  ORDER BY msg_id DESC
   LIMIT 1 ) AS MAX_receiver_id,   
  t1.*
from messaging t1
group by 1;`

Comment: Is there any way to get only unique sender and receiver column UNIQUE like DISTINCT?

Comment: I apologize, but unfortunately I could not fully understand your need.
The above query will only bring a record of `sender_id` and `receiver_id` which in this case makes them unique (for each `sender_id` there will be only one `receiver_id`), the fact that the record of `receiver_id`
duplicate gives several `sender_id` relate to `receiver_id`
I could not fully understand your need, let me know more details about it

Comment: I want to get list of users and last message between that user and me like when we open any messaging app. only last message between users

Comment: the problem is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376559/get-unique-list-of-conversation-like-what-we-see-in-any-messaging-app-in-mysql

Comment: I updated the link to: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b206f/4] as I needed to use more information such as dates and times. Well, I used the following logic, I present the last record of sending a message from `sender_id`, to the address `receiver_id` containing the text of the message and etc..
Let me know if it helped

Comment: the link show empty fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249456/discussion-between-techedifice-and-elivan-fengler-backes).

Comment: thank you so much. you saved my day! God must have sent u to save me.